# Занесение текста в виджет Label tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
#Отрывок кода
alpha_ru = {'.-' : 'а', '-...' : 'б', '.--' : 'в',
        '--.' : 'г', '-..' : 'д', '.' : 'е',
        '...-' : 'ж', '--..' : 'з', '..' : 'и',
        '.---' : 'й', '-.-' : 'к', '.-..' : 'л',
        '--' : 'м', '-.' : 'н', '---' : 'о',
        '.--.' : 'п', '.-.' : 'р', '...' : 'с',
        '-' : 'т', '..-' : 'у', '..-.' : 'ф',
        '....' : 'х', '-.-.' : 'ц', '---.' : 'ч',
        '----' : 'ш', '--.-' : 'щ',
        '-.--' : 'ы', '-..-' : '(ь, ъ)', '..--..' : 'э',
        '..--' : 'ю', '.-.-' : 'я',
        '-----' : '0', '.----' : '1', '..---' : '2',
        '...--' : '3', '....-' : '4', '.....' : '5',
        '-....' : '6', '--...' : '7', '---..' : '8',
        '----.' : '9',
        '......' : '.', '--..--' : '!', '..--..' : '?',
        '---...' : ':', '-.-.-.' : ';', '-....-' : '-',
        '-..-.' : '/', '.-..-.' : '"', '-.--.' : '(',
        '-.--.-' : ')', '-...-' : '=', '.-.-.' : '+',
        '...-..-' : '$' , '.-.-..' : '¶', '..--.-' : '_',
        '.-.-.-' : ',', '' : ' '}
def main():
    res = (entry.get()).split(' ')
    for i in res:
        translate = ''
        translate += alpha_ru[i]
        lbl4 = Label(root, text=translate) 
        lbl4.place(x=10, y=240)
```

Этот код переводит из алфавита Морзе в русский язык. В цикле `for` я столкнулся с такой проблемой:
В строке кода `lbl4 = Label(root, text=translate)` в переменную `lbl4` должна записываться переменная `translate`, т.е. когда я подаю на ввод строку `.--. .-. .. .-- . - .-.-.-  -- .. .-. --..--`, что означает "привет, мир!", в переменную `lbl4` должен записываться "привет, мир!", а записывается, только последний символ (т.е. "!"). Как мне сделать так, чтобы записывалось все слово?
Я могу отправить полный код, но, я не думаю, что он будет понятен, т.к. написал его на скорую руку и еще не привел в порядок. Я надеюсь, что этого куска будет достаточно..

Comment: надо вынести всё кроме `translate += alpha_ru[i]` из цикла

Answer (score 1):

Собственно, обычный цикл вам вообще не нужен, лучше использовать *списковое включение*, чтобы не путаться в инициализации переменных и т.д.:

```
res = '.--. .-. .. .-- . - .-.-.-  -- .. .-. --..--'.split(' ')
translate = ''.join([alpha_ru[w] for w in res])
print(translate)
```

Вывод:

```
привет, мир!
```